# Java server running, but can only access via local host

Tags: java, linux, sockets, ubuntu, port

Not quite sure how to put this. I have a java server running on the background on port 12000.
it is running on a linux machine, I can access and use it via localhost just fine, but when I try to access it from another computer, It cannot be found.
I have disable uwf firewall and still can't access it.
what else do I need to do?

```
ServerSocket theSocket = new ServerSocket(portNum);
Socket incoming = null;     // new connection.
boolean incomingOK = true;  // is connection established?
while (!closeRequested){

// to get next client
   incoming = theSocket.accept( );
.
.
}
```

This is how I open the port through java. As I said before, The server works fine on localhost. the trouble is I can't get it to connect from an external machine.

Comment: Well what kind of server is it? How have you specified the port to open? There's not enough information here at the moment.

Comment: show the code where you are telling it to bind/ listen. What IP are you telling it to bind to.  If you want all IPS you can tell it to listen on 0.0.0.0.  also take a look at `netstat -an | grep 12000 ` to show what IP(s) it is listening on

Comment: Networking questions are probably more fitted to http://serverfault.com/

Comment: How are you trying to access the server? which IP address is it assigned? Are the two computers in the same network? if you are using a domain name, have you set the host in your local machine?

Comment: well as he is coding a network server, it could still be On Topic Here, as it could be a programming question related to socket binding

Comment: I also have another silly question. did I choose a right topic for this question? what I'm try to say is that if using ServerSocket is basically java server?

Comment: "external machine".  Is this a machine that is on the other side of a router somewhere?  For instance, is your linux box sitting in your room and you are trying to access it from the coffeeshop down the street?  If so, you will need to forward a port on your router

Comment: @RussellUhl yes, my external machine is in another country :). the server is running on amazon cloud, by default it had ports 8080,22 and 3306 open. but any other thing can't be accessed for some reason.

Comment: well there you go.  if only those ports are open, then you need to talk to your amazon cloud rep and see if you can open a different port.  I have no experience with amazon cloud, so I don't know if that is even possible (I would assume it is).  They will have to work some routing magic on their end before you are able to connect.

Comment: @Doon Hi, I just checked **bold** 'netstat -an | grep 12000'. I get the folloing: **tcp6  0  0 :::12000    :::*    LISTEN'**. interestingly when I check for  **netstat -an | grep 12000** I get  **tcp  0  0 0.0.0.0:22       0.0.0.0:*     LISTEN**. So I'm just wondering how do I add **0.0.0.0** for port **12000**. that might solve my problem